# Grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul missing dir error

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, istanbul

I install grunt plugins grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul

```
npm install grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul --save-dev
```

and add to Gruntfile.js as following:

```
coverage: {
    src: ['app/scripts/**/*.js'],
    options: {
        specs: ['test/**/*.js'],
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
        templateOptions: {
            coverage: 'test/coverage/coverage.json',
            report: [
               {type:'html',options: {dir: 'test/coverage/html'}},
               {type:'text',options: {dir: 'test/coverage/text'}},
               {type:'text'},
            ],
            thresholds: {
                lines: 75,
                statements: 75,
                branches: 75,
                functions: 90
            }
        }
    }
},
```

but when running test it **shown following warning and no report** in test/coverage folder:

```
my@computer:/share/angularjs-gs$ grunt test:coverage
Running "coverage" task
Warning: "dir" option is required. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've also created test/coverage/html and test/converage/text folder. I also view code from plugin's author but cannot find any solution: https://github.com/maenu/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul-example/blob/connect/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it, must wrap coverage object by jasmine, it maybe that coverage used as jasmine plugin but spec and src attribute seems being redundant.

```
  jasmine: {
    coverage: {
        src: ['app/scripts/**/*.js'],
        options: {
            specs: ['test/**/*.js'],
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
            templateOptions: {
                coverage: 'test/coverage/coverage.json',
                report: [
                   {type:'html',options: {dir: 'test/coverage/html'}},
                   {type:'text',options: {dir: 'test/coverage/text/'}},
                   {type:'text-summary'}
                ],
                thresholds: {
                    lines: 75,
                    statements: 75,
                    branches: 75,
                    functions: 90
                }
            }
        }
```